# Is there seasonality or trend in the attached time series graph

Tags: seasonality

[image]

Is there trend or seasonality in the attached time series graph ?

Comment: I think, there an upward trend. Why don't use the ACF plot like [this](http://coolstatsblog.com/2013/08/11/how-to-use-autocorreation-function-acf-to-determine-seasonality/) to check for seasonality?

Comment: You may find it easier to detect these if you transform your data to group the same "seasons" together and plot against time. For instance, let's say you have monthly data. Then plot a line for all the Januaries on the vertical axis agains increasing year on the x. Repeat for the other 11 months. Put it all on the same graph if not too cluttered.